# Sharing web application for different clients

Tags: java, grails

Our framework is Grails. Say domain.com contains an application and currently used by some client. If we want to allow another client *with the same functionality* but providing a *separation* for the data of two clients, so that they can't mix both, how to do this? And whenever we want to add n clients to this application, what is the best method to be followed, so that *with less / no configuration* we can share the common war file for these clients by separating the db.

How the real time web development handle these type of situations?

And, one more point is how to provide client1.domain.com works for client1 and client2.domain.com works for client2. How to make the war file (in Java / Grails) to work like this? Otherwise we have to programmatically control the clients with in the project for every feature to be allowed or unnecessarily maintain separate war file for each client, which will be a waste of resources.

Comment: I would first create two subdomains. One for each client. Deploy the application two times. Each configured to another datasource and than put an apache server in front of the webapps with 2 virtual host entries and a mod_jk configuration.

Comment: @RenéLink Thanks for the reply. So, when if any new user registers for the application, how to dynamically do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're describing multitenancy - create one table for N 'tenants' instead of N identical (or nearly) tables, but partition it with a tenant_id column, and use that to filter results in SQL WHERE clauses.

For example the generated code for `findByUsername` would be something like `select * from person where username='foo' and tenant_id=3'` - the same code as a regular call but with the tenant_id column to restrict within that tenant's data.

Note that previously simple things like unique constraints are now harder because you would want to restrict uniqueness within a tenant, but allow a value to be reused across tenants. In this case changing the unique constraint to be on the combo of username and tenant_id works and does the heavy lifting in the database.

For a while there were several related plugins, but they relied on tweaking internal APIs and some features broke in newer Hibernate versions. But I believe that http://grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-single-db is active; it was updated over a year ago, but it is being used. Contact the authors if it looks like it'll be what you need to be sure it's active. Note that this can only work with Hibernate 3.x.

Hibernate 4 added support for multitenancy, but I haven't heard much about its use in Grails (which is expected, since it's not that common a requirement). It's not well documented, but this bug report highlights some of the potential pitfalls and should still be a working example (the test app is still on GitHub): https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPHIB-6.

I'd like to ensure that this is working and continues to work, so please let me know via email if you have issues later. It's a great feature and having it in Hibernate core makes things a lot easier for us. But we need to make it easy to use and well-documented, and that will happen a lot faster when it's being used in a real project.